# C# consumo de libreria externa .dll

Tags: c#, dll

Me encuentro en la situación de consumir una .dll externa la cual conecta mediante COM a un hardware.

La conexión y desconexión sale exitosa.

Ahora bien a la hora de consumir otro método interno, el cual al enviar unos datos, el mismo método llena el output en base a como salio la operación.. puedo enviar el input exitosamente por que lo veo en el hardware. Pero no logro recibir el output.

Les comparto documentacion de la DLL

```
WORD __stdcall sanGateway(sanGatewayIn_t* intput, sanTrxOut_t* output, LONG timeout);

typedef struct SANgatewayIN{

   LPSTR am;
   LPSTR receip;
   LPSTR plan;
   LPSTR cuit;
   Char  mode;

}sanGatewayIn_t

typedef struct SAN_TRX_OUT{

   LPSTR hostRespCode;
   LPSTR message;
   LPSTR date;
   LPSTR time;

}sanTrxOut_t;
```

Y este es mi codigo en C#

```
[DllImport(@"sanGateway.dll", EntryPoint = "sanGateway", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl )]
public static extern int sanGateway (Gateway_In intput, Gateway_Out output, long timeout);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]

public struct Gateway_Out
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 2)]
    public string hostRespCode;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 32)]
    public string message;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 11)]
    public string date;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr, SizeConst = 9)]
    public string time;
   

    public Gateway_Out(string hostRespCode, string message, string date, string time)
    {
        this.hostRespCode = hostRespCode;
        this.message = message;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
    }

}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public class Gateway_In
{
    private string am;
    private string receip;
    private string plan;
    private string cuit;
    private char mode;

    public Gateway_In() { }
        
    public Gateway_In(string am, string receip, string plan, string cuit, char mode)
    {
        this.am = am;
        this.receip = receip;
        this.plan = plan;
        this.cuit = cuit;
        this.mode = mode;
    }
}
```

Al ejecutar lo siguiente
( no adjunto la inicializacion del input, pero es en base a la declaracion de arriba.. y eso funciona.):

```
int result = sanGateway(input, output, 60);
```

al ejecutarla cuando tiene que llenar el output, tengo los problemas.

Probé de poner

CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl

y tambien probé

CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall

pruebe lo que pruebe siempre tengo algún error que no logra llenar el output o no recibo ningun error y termina saliendo por timeout.

El error mas comun que obtengo es:

```
System.AccessViolationException: 
'Intento de leer o escribir en la memoria protegida.A menudo, esto indica que hay otra memoria dañada.'
```

Pienso que viene asociado a la construcción de mi struct Gateway_Out, pero realmente no logro darme cuenta.

Toda ayuda será mas que bienvenida!